# How to find a name in a name/value pair using cJSON

Tags: c, cjson

cJSON provides a function

`CJSON_PUBLIC(cJSON *) cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(const cJSON * const object, const char * const string)`

I created a test function

```
#include "cJSON.h"
const char *jsonstring = "{\"b\": {\"b1\":\"2b\"}}";

void jsontest(void)
{
  cJSON *cJSON_data = cJSON_Parse(jsonstring);
  char *buffer = cJSON_Print(cJSON_data);
  printf("JSON_String:%s\r\n",buffer);
  cJSON *bfound = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(cJSON_data,"b1");
  printf("bfound: 0x%08x\n",(char*)bfound);
  free(cJSON_data);
  free(buffer);
}
```

The output is

```
JSON_String:{
    "b":    {
        "b1":   "2b"
    }
}

bfound: 0x00000000
```

`

If I use this string,

`const char *jsonteststr1 = "{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"2\",\"c\":\"3\"}";`

`GetObjectItemCaseSensitive()` will find "a", "b", and "c".

`GetObjectItemCaseSensitive()` does not seem to recurse.

Am I doing something wrong? Do I not understand how to use `GetObjectItem()`?

I am using version 1.7.12

Comment: Use the `%p` format specifier to print memory addresses.

Comment: And cast to `void *`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments on coding.,

Answer (score 2):

`cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(object, string)` can only get the the direct child and child's siblings of `object`, we can't find the child's child node through it.

if you want to get the value of `2b`, then you should:

```c
#include "cJSON.h"
const char *jsonstring = "{\"b\": {\"b1\":\"2b\"}}";

void jsontest(void)
{
  cJSON *cJSON_data = cJSON_Parse(jsonstring);
  char *buffer = cJSON_Print(cJSON_data);
  printf("JSON_String:%s\r\n",buffer);
  cJSON *bfound = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(cJSON_data,"b");  // cJSON_data only has a child which named "b"
  cJSON *b1_found = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(bfound, "b1");  // key/value: <b1, 2b> is in b1_found, not bfound
  printf("b1_found: 0x%08x\n",(char*)b1_found);
  printf("bfound: 0x%08x\n",(char*)bfound);

  cJSON_Delete(cJSON_data);  // you should use cJSON_Delete to free the json item.
  free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: hi, there is no method to retrieve a value on a provided key ? In json, keys are supposed to be unique, so the method does make sense to me.